# How is this unit test passing when exercised?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have made two variables of which both are not equal, I have created a `if` statement for the method and on visual studio it still passes, only way I got it to fail was if I removed the `if` statement completely and then used

```
Assert.IsTrue(a == b);
```

But if I try using it through `if` statements it passes for some reason

```
[TestClass]
public class SectionQuiz
{
   static int a;         
    static int  b;              

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void IntegerInitalize(TestContext testContext)
    {
        a = 10;  // set variables and a != b
        b = 5;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Number1_isnotequalto_number2()
    {
        if (a == b)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(a==b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *it passes for some reason* means you will see the green dot in test explorer?

Comment: @GrizzlyBear please try **not** to edit the original question beyond the point where the existing answers loose context. Instead, either _append_ the follow up in same question (if it is a related small doubt), else _post_ a fresh question and mention previous one if required.

Answer (score 2):

The if statement has nothing to do with it passing or not. The unit test **Number1_isnotequalto_number2** isn't asserting anything so it will always pass.

Add this line to the end of the unit test **Number1_isnotequalto_number2** and outside of the if statement.

```
Assert.AreEqual(a, b);
```

By adding this line, the unit test should always fail, given your initialization.

**Another option** - if you want to combine if statements with asserts, but its normally not done like this...

```
if (a != b)
  Assert.Fail("they are not equal");
// else
// There is no Assert.Pass - just return and it passes
```

Comment: Thank you my dude, I tried upvoting your comment; but for some reason it doesn't change. So I am learning this course and this lady is showing it through if statements for the unit tests; so a bit confused. So my question is would you be able to do this through if statements and asserts combined rather than just asserts @dodgy_coder

Comment: @GrizzlyBear No problem, yes you can do it with ifs and asserts.. I will edit my answer ...

Comment: @GrizzlyBear please keep in mind that writing your unit tests using if statements is a horrible idea. If there is an equivalent assert instruction, use it. Maybe ask that lady why she teaches this way.